# 'Id' is not an index in this table - MS ACCESS

Tags: ms-access

I am getting errors in Access when attempting to open both the database
and the table.

Error: **'Id' is not an index in this table**

Please help me,  this is in production.

May Anyone Please share their expertise if come across with same scenario

Comment: Please provide more details when the error appears. Are you able to see table data? Make compact-repair, try to re-create table  by coping or importing to another database. Drop and create again indexes. Looks like a damage in table data or structure

Comment: @SergeyS.This Error occured when ever i am trying to open Database and any of the
table in it.

i tried with repair, but no improvement. please suggest

Comment: That's bad. Create blank database and try to import tables from damaged database

Comment: Try those steps: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-47.html

Comment: @SergeyS.: Thanks SergeyS: i am trying to do as given in a link.

Comment: If it's in production, you sure have a backup...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that database corrupted.
Try to restore database as it described [here](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-47.html). Also check [this](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/corruption/symptoms.htm), item 20 and [this](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/corruption/retrievedata.htm). And finally check how to [prevent corruption](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-25.html).

Answer (score 1):

I also had this error message. Unfortunately the links provided by Sergey only helped in so far as that it became clear to me that my Current DB was unrecoverable.

I fixed the issue by:

1. Creating a new Access DB
2. Manually exporting each table from the old one (Access still allowed me to export to another DB, eventhough I got the error message on each and every export)
3. Recreating all necessary relationships between tables in the DB

Note: This solution worked well for me because the error appeared in the backend of my DB. If you have an unsplit DB, this could be a huge effort.